# Capture the preview of a UIImagePickerController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, camera, screenshot, uiimagepickercontroller

This has been asked many times. But most answers are not applicable to the latest OS (3.0+) or they are "Apple will reject it".

What I need is to programmatically grab the image displayed in the preview of the UIImagePickerController without having the user take a photo and use the image - what I actually need is to get a screenshot of my app, which contains the camera in the background and other stuff on the foreground.

I have tried several methods, with the latest being: iterate through all the subviews of the UIImagePickerController.view and save them as images using the `[view.layer renderInContext:]` method. With this method, I can actually get all the controller's assets (the buttons etc) but I can never see the actual preview. Has anyone figured a way to do this in 3.0+ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been answered in [question 1317978](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1317978/iphone-get-camera-preview) already. Also, have a look at [the blog post describing live grabbing in sudoku solver](http://cmgresearch.blogspot.com/2010/01/augmented-reality-on-iphone-how-to_01.html)