# ios take multiple pictures without user interaction

Tags: ios, camera, compatibility, avfoundation

I have been researching for this and read different opinions but i wanted to ask you more specific questions.

In my application i want to take 3 or 4 frames from the camera stream to process them without making the user press a button multiple times (and as fast as posible), i do this already on the android version, because android provides a callback method that contains each frame of the camera feed.

I have seen some people using the iOS AVFoundation (classes AVCaptureDevice, AVCaptureInput) to perform this tasks, but as far as i know, this is supported from version 4.0 of iOS.

Is there another way to do this and support older iOS versions? like 3.X?
how fast can the different pictures be taken?
Are there still problems using this Framework to get Apps/updates accepted on the App Store?

Thanks a lot,

Alex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the new way (AVCaptureInput), as only a few percent of users still use iOS 3.  iOS adoption is much faster than android adoption.  Early last winter about 90% had already upgraded to 4.  At this point even 4.0 is likely in the small minority as well.

One pre-ios-4 way to do it was by opening a UIImagePickerController and taking screenshots.  Depending on the exact version targeted, there are sometimes ways to disable the camera overlays.

I see this question: [iPhone: Get camera preview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1317978/iphone-get-camera-preview)