# Capture Screen on Camera

Tags: ios, iphone, camera

Helo Everyone. I want to capture screenshot when camera is appeared. The scenario is I'm adding an overlay view to camera. And when user adjusts camera and tapp capture button. I want to generate an image what is on screen. I've tried screen shot by using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1317978/iphone-get-camera-preview) code but only overlay is capture not the image. That is camera is blank.

I've also seen [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1702/_index.html) answer

but it only captures image not the overlay view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take the image received from the `UIImagePickerController` (the one received in `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo` method from the delegate) and merge it with your overlay view like this :

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

    UIImage *cameraImage = The image captured by the camera;
    UIImage *overlayImage = Your overlay;
    UIImage *computedImage = nil;

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(cameraImage.size, NO, 0.0f);
    [cameraImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, cameraImage.size.width, cameraImage.size.height)];
    [overlayImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, overlayImage.size.width, overlayImage.size.height)];

    computedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
       // don't forget to go back to the main thread to access the UI again
    });
});
```

**EDIT :** I added some dispatch_async to avoid blocking the UI

Comment: well it was not complete answer but it helped me. Thanks for suggestion. Still I've not the perfect solution but developer knows... :P